# biblatex: How to modify the ieee-alphabetic to group papers by authors?

Tags: biblatex, ieeetran

When using the `ieee-alphabetic` template for `biblatex`, it gives

```
[author1-year1; author1-year2; ...; auhtor2-year1; author2-year2,....]
```

in my pdf.

I manage to get the years arranged in the numerical order.
How can I get it to concatenate the author1 since sometimes I have several papers from the same (bunch of) authors:

```
[author1--year1--year2--...;author2--year1--year2--...]
```

in such a manner that the hyperreferences (the clickable red rectangles) will be on each --year1 --year2 and so on ?

Comment: On my system, `ieee-alphabetic` produces output such as `[Ord83]` or `[AS97]`, in such cases concatenating labels - I think - would only lead to ambiguities. Could you hand us a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)?

Comment: Note that `biblatex-ieee` is really just a thin 'wrapper' to use the `alphabetic` label style with IEEE-like bibliography entries.

Comment: I do not have a MWE since I do not how how to start; to illustrate http://izipik.com/images/201309/06/1j8xksg45859ht44964uz-cbx.png the first is the traditional output, the second line is what I desired.